how to fix the sculpting?
I was making a football stadium, when I wanted to make the spike things into the smoothed and squished crimp like things as shown in the reference, in sculpting, the brush lies flat on the surface... however it's not in this case and I have a lot of geometry in this object, so it should be no problem here and my normals are set from faces... blender 4.1...(I'm an absolute beginner so don't judge me by that tho)


Hello, could you please show some pictures of the spike thing? I doubt using sculpt tools is a good idea, it's ok for organic shapes but not clean, regular and symmetrical shapes...

k adding more pictures

do you have some pictures of your reference object? It's probably better to make your object with an Array then Simple Deform to make it circular

sry for late updation but yea... here it is, the refrence

Ok so try it with an Array + Curve modifier?

I'mnot sure why you want to use the Sculpt tool, instead you could create this segment:

Array it with 2 Array modifiers on X and Y:

Create this bezier curve:

Give your segment a Curve modifier with this curve as curve object:


thanks... I'm new to blender so thats why I thought to do every spike thingy individually, thats great help!
